# Better way to calculate double-scattering diffraction using cartesian product of arrays?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, memory-management, physics

This script calculates points in reciprocal space for hexagonal 2D lattices, then uses the [cartesian product from itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to add each vector from one lattice to all of the vectors of the other in the line

```
np.array([a+b for a, b in list(itertools.product(p1.T, p2.T))])
```

It's slow right now because as written its instantiating millions of tiny numpy arrays.

I'm aware of:

- [Cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11144716)
- [Using numpy to build an array of all combinations of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1208118)
- [cartesian products in numPy](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/10748)

and I suspect there's some way to do this, possibly using `np.meshgrid`  or `np.mgrid` that's faster, uses less memory and looks cleaner, but I can not figure out how.

I will use the output in an optimization loop matching these positions to measured positions, so it needs to be callable several hundred times in a row, so reusing large array spaces rather than instantiating and garbage collecting them might have some advantages.

[image: simulated diffraction spots] click for larger

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

def rotatem(xy, rot):
    r3o2, twopi, to_degs, to_rads = np.sqrt(3)/2., 2*np.pi, 180/np.pi, np.pi/180
    c, s = [f(to_rads*rot) for f in (np.cos, np.sin)]
    x, y = xy
    xr = c*x - s*y
    yr = c*y + s*x
    return np.vstack((xr, yr))

def get_points(a=1.0, nmax=5, rot=0):
    r3o2, twopi, to_degs, to_rads = np.sqrt(3)/2., 2*np.pi, 180/np.pi, np.pi/180
    g = twopi / (r3o2 * a)
    i = np.arange(-nmax, nmax+1)
    I, J = [thing.flatten() for thing in np.meshgrid(i, i)]
    keep = np.abs(I + J) <= nmax
    I, J = [thing[keep] for thing in (I, J)]
    xy = np.vstack((I+0.5*J, r3o2*J))
    return g * rotatem(xy, rot=rot)

r3o2, twopi, to_degs, to_rads = np.sqrt(3)/2., 2*np.pi, 180/np.pi, np.pi/180

a1, a2, rot = 1.0, 2**0.2, 22

p1 = get_points(a=a1, nmax=20)
p2 = get_points(a=a2, nmax=20, rot=rot)
p3 = get_points(a=a2, nmax=20, rot=-rot)

d12 = np.array([a+b for a, b in list(itertools.product(p1.T, p2.T))])
d13 = np.array([a+b for a, b in list(itertools.product(p1.T, p3.T))])
d12, d13 = [d[((d**2).sum(axis=1)<4.)] for d in (d12, d13)]

if True:
    plt.figure()
    for d in (d12, d13):
        plt.plot(*d.T, 'o', ms=2)
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: This comment won't be a solution to the main question at hand, but it's important to understand that you don't need the two intermediate lists created in your first line of code. Instead, just write this: `np.array(a+b for a, b in itertools.product(p1.T, p2.T))`. The same point could be made about the creation of `d12` and `d13` in your larger code example.

Comment: @FMc While `d12 = np.array(a+b for a, b in list(itertools.product(p1.T, p2.T)))` is accepted, the next step `d12 = np.array(d12[((d12**2).sum(axis=1)<4.)])` throws an exception "unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'generator' and 'int"

Answer (score 2):

You can replace:

```
d12 = np.array([a+b for a, b in list(itertools.product(p1.T, p2.T))])
```

with something like:

```
p1 = p1.T
p2 = p2.T
p3 = p3.T
d12 = p1[:,np.newaxis,:] + p2[np.newaxis,:,:]
d12 = my_d12.reshape((len(p1)*len(p2),2))
```

I find it most of the times easier to use the first index of an array for *point_index* and the second index for the dimensions, hence the `.T`'s

With the use of the *magic* index [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) at the right places you can create numpy array's of shape (M,N) with normal operators acting on arrays of shape (M) and (N).

With the `reshape` method `d12` changed again to the shape in your original solution.

Comment: Oh this is great! So simple; exactly what's needed. I've always used `None` in the place of `np.newaxis` thinking they did the same thing but never checked.

Comment: @uhoh, you can also use `None` because `np.newaxis` is only an alias of `None`. I prefer to use `np.newaxis` because it is a heads-up that there is something funny going on with indexes and [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: Okay got it! I think I will switch to that as well since I've been soundly reprimanded for poor readability ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty cluttered and you seem fixated on a 'less lines of code equals better code' mindset.

Firstly lets move `r3o2` and friends out into the global scope as constants - `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` variables in Python.
This gets rid of 2 lines of code. Additionally it and makes:

- `rotatem` less confusing as now you're not defining 3 things you never use.
- `get_points` less confusing as now you're not defining 2 things you never use.

To get `rotatem` to look cleaner I'd then go on to:

1. Move the expression for defining `xr` and `yr` into the return.
2. Get rid of the clunky tuple unpacked comprehension; just write it out.
3. Use better names than `c` and `s`; `cos` and `sin` could be far more readable.
   I moved them to the latter side of multiplication so the equation doesn't look like \$\sin x - \cos y\$

This makes `rotatem` pretty readable now.

```py
def rotatem(xy, rot):
    x, y = xy
    cos = np.cos(TO_RADS * rot)
    sin = np.sin(TO_RADS * rot)
    return np.vstack((
        x*cos - y*sin,
        y*cos + x*sin,
    ))
```

To get `get_points` to look cleaner I'd then go on to:

1. Move the definition of `g` down to the bottom of the function. By defining it at the top of the function I'm having to read each and every line of code in the function to see if `g` is used. This is just a waste of time when you only use it in the `return`.
2. Rename:

   - `i` to `domain`,
   - `I` to `i`, and
   - `J` to `j`.
3. Split the tuple in the expression for `xy` over multiple lines.
4. Change `i` to `i[keep]` and `j` to `j[keep]`; remove the tuple comprehension before this.
5. Add some whitespace around operators.

This makes `get_points` a bit more readable. But `np.meshgrid` is hampering this a bit.

```py
def get_points(a=1.0, nmax=5, rot=0):
    domain = np.arange(-nmax, nmax + 1)
    i, j = [thing.flatten() for thing in np.meshgrid(domain, domain)]
    keep = np.abs(i + j) <= nmax
    xy = np.vstack((
        i[keep] + 0.5 * j[keep],
        R3O2 * j[keep],
    ))
    return (TWO_PI / (R3O2 * a)) * rotatem(xy, rot=rot)
```

I still don't really understand what your code is doing, what are `rotatem` and `get_points` doing? You can explain this at the top of each function by using a docstring.

It's taken me a while to understand your code this much, and I still don't see myself understanding it all any time soon. You should really try to improve the readability of your code to the best it can be in the future so others don't just get bored.

In case you think my changes will decrease performance by anything important, my changes have a negligible impact on performance.

```
$ python orig.py
0.0005879989994355128 4.213629218999813
$ python peil.py
0.0005172819992367295 4.236298889999489
```

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import timeit

R3O2 = np.sqrt(3) / 2.
TWO_PI = 2 * np.pi  # You could just call this tau.
TO_DEGS = 180 / np.pi
TO_RADS = np.pi / 180


def rotatem(xy, rot):
    """Explain what rotatem does."""
    x, y = xy
    cos = np.cos(rot)
    sin = np.sin(rot)
    return np.vstack((
        x*cos - y*sin,
        y*cos + x*sin,
    ))


def get_points(a=1.0, nmax=5, rot=0):
    """Explain what get_points does."""
    domain = np.arange(-nmax, nmax + 1)
    i, j = [thing.flatten() for thing in np.meshgrid(domain, domain)]
    keep = np.abs(i + j) <= nmax
    xy = np.vstack((
        i[keep] + 0.5 * j[keep],
        R3O2 * j[keep],
    ))
    return (TWO_PI / (R3O2 * a)) * rotatem(xy, rot=rot)


def main(a1, a2, rot):
    timer = timeit.perfcounter()
    start = timer()

    p1 = get_points(a=a1, nmax=20)
    p2 = get_points(a=a2, nmax=20, rot=TO_RADS * rot)
    p3 = get_points(a=a2, nmax=20, rot=TO_RADS * -rot)

    mid = timer()

    d12 = np.array([a+b for a, b in list(itertools.product(p1.T, p2.T))])
    d13 = np.array([a+b for a, b in list(itertools.product(p1.T, p3.T))])
    d12, d13 = [d[((d**2).sum(axis=1)<4.)] for d in (d12, d13)]

    stop = timer()
    print(mid - start, stop - start)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(1.0, 2**0.2, 22)
```

Comment: "I still don't really understand what your code is doing..." & "...my changes have a negligible impact on performance." Got it.

Comment: @uhoh If you'd have followed my answer before I'd posted it then you'd get a better answer. Instead due to you not caring about readability or explaining what your code does it's just a waste of our time.

Comment: @uhoh You can also fix this by writing docstrings and improving the readability of your code so your code is accessible to anyone that reads it. Even more so when you put it up for critique.

Comment: I'm revisiting this problem and rediscovered your answer, it's quite helpful now that I've had more "life experience", thanks!

Comment: @uhoh Sorry I failed at making my answer helpful for the you in the past. I'm happy to hear my answer became more helpful now.

Comment: I do a lof of things in parallel and sometimes I need to just put something aside for a while until it "clicks" or until I gain more depth and/or context. Both Python and Stack Exchange are gifts that keep on giving :-)